# Dictionary all for one

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I print all dictionary items (keys and values) in one line. for example:

```
dicMyDictionary = {michael:jordan, kobe:bryant, lebron:james} 

print(?)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The question might get closed soon if you don't explain at the earliest.

Comment: print(dicMyDictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, just printing the dictionary itself will print everything on one line:

```
>>> dicMyDictionary = {"michael":"jordan", "kobe":"bryant", "lebron":"james"}
>>> print(dicMyDictionary)
{'kobe': 'bryant', 'michael': 'jordan', 'lebron': 'james'}
```

If you want to format it in some way:

```
>>> print(' '.join(str(key)+":"+str(value) for key,value in dicMyDictionary.iteritems()))
kobe:bryant michael:jordan lebron:james
```

ref: [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [dict.iteritems](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems)

Or with a `for` loop for more detailed control:

```
>>> formatted_str = ""
>>> for key,value in dicMyDictionary.iteritems():
        formatted_str += "(key: " + str(key) + " value:" + value + ") "
>>> print(formatted_str)
(key: kobe value:bryant) (key: michael value:jordan) (key: lebron value:james)
```

ref: [dict.iteritems](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems),[Python looping techniques](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Comment: Had a brain fart and forgot about passing the dict itself, I'm still new to python, thanks for the added formatting example.

Comment: @TrayTray no problem! I've found the best practice with a language like python is to just try things and watch them blow up in your face ^_^

Comment: I know plenty about that. I come from a C++/C# background so the no  braces thing still irks my nerves.

Comment: @TrayTray ahhhh I see I see, yeah it can be a little unsettling at first, its an acquired taste for sure, Enjoy!